# Issue in converting list to numpy array in python

Tags: python, list, numpy

I'm trying to convert a list into `numpy` array. By doing so all the integers are converted into characters. How can i avoid it?

```
import numpy as np
X_man = np.array([600, 'France', 'Female', 40, 3, 60000, 2, 1, 1, 50000])
print(X_man)

output:

['600' 'France' 'Female' '40' '3' '60000' '2' '1' '1' '50000']
```

Comment: Use : `X_man=np.array([600,'France','Female',40,3,60000,2,1,1,50000],dtype=object)`.

Comment: Why use numpy to store a collection of heterogeneous objects?